# Return a str - Rust Lifetimes

Tags: rust

I am running into some trouble when trying to return a string. I have been trying various ways of defining my variables and return value to try and make it so I can return the string primitive, but I get an array of lifetime related error messages.

```
pub fn raindrops(int: u64) -> &'a str {
    let mut out = String::new();

    if int % 3 == 0 {
        out.push_str("Pling");
    }
    if int % 5 == 0 {
        out.push_str("Plang");
    }
    if int % 7 == 0 {
        out.push_str("Plong");
    }
    if out.is_empty() {
        out.push_str(&format!("{}", int));
    }

    out.shrink_to_fit();

    return out.as_str();
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:32
  |
1 | pub fn raindrops(int: u64) -> &'a str {
  |                                ^^ undeclared lifetime

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `raindrops`.
Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:32
  |
1 | pub fn raindrops(int: u64) -> &'a str {
  |                                ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

Comment: You might find this interesting https://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return a `&str` in this situation, because it would point to the contents of `out` which goes out of scope at the end of the function. You have to return the String `out` instead.

Alternatively, if you want to limit allocations, you could return an enum which can be one of:

```
Pling,
Plang,
Plong,
Other(u64)
```

and then print the response based on the value.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I guess I was over complicating it.

Comment: As an optimization, one may return Cow instead of String. This will ensure that no dynamic allocation happens if one returns static string.